Публикация ASP.NET-проекта с помощью командной строки
Для публикации ASP.NET-проекта в локальную папку через командную строку использую:
msbuild <путь до csproj-файла> /p:PublishProfile=<профиль публикации>

При этом получаю ошибку:
... .csproj(603,3): error MSB4019: импортированный проект "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targ
ets" не обнаружен. Проверьте путь в объявлении <Import> и наличие файла на диске.

строка 603 .csproj-файла:
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

Указанной в ошибке папки "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio" нет. При этом публикация проекта через саму Visual Studio (ПКМ по проекту -> Опубликовать) работает корректно.
Дополнительно указывал версию студии через
/p:VisualStudioVersion

Версия студии - 2019.
Необходимо добавить какой-то параметр к команде?
